# OperationUnsupportedError working with Lists clojure-java interop

Tags: opencv, clojure, interop

I have the following open-cv interop code:

```
(defn find-significant-contours [edge-img size]
    (def contours '())
    (def hierarchy (Mat. size cv/CV_8UC1))
    (def edge-img-8u (Mat. size cv/CV_8UC1))
    (cv/find-contours edge-img-8u contours hierarchy cv/RETR_TREE cv/CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
)
```

where the findContours java function is:

```
public static void findContours​(Mat image, java.util.List<MatOfPoint> contours, Mat hierarchy, int mode, int method)
```

but upon doing (find-significant-countours (Mat. size cv/CV_32FC1) img-size), I get the error:

```
(UnsupportedOperationException) at
   org.opencv.utils.Converters/Mat_to_vector_vector_Point (Converters.java:542).
```

I think it is because findCountours asks for a List, whereas I'm giving a '(). I don't know how to explicitly give a List. Or the error might be because of some other reason. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My _guess_ is, that this code wants to `.add()` to the seq - and clojure data structures are immutable. Have you tried passing an actual list?  E.g. `(java.util.ArrayList.)`

Comment: @cfrick Correct diagnosis, but I take issue with "actual list". Clojure's lists are actual instances of java.util.List, as evidenced by the code not causing a ClassCastException. They are not *mutable* lists, and this method wants a mutable list.

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` is an expected outcome from a `java.util.List` that is not mutable, according to the javadoc at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html. As @cfrick suggests you can try using a mutable list. Even Clojure uses mutable lists, when it needs to: for example, see the source code for `partition-all`, linked from the Clojure API docs at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/partition-all

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown from the Clojure sequence implementation, that don't support `.add(...)`-ing items to itself, as it is immutable.

You have to pass an `List` implementation, that supports adding items.  E.g. `(java.util.ArrayList.)`